# In RBAC, is there a need for "superadmin" permissions?

Tags: php, mysql, authorization, access-control, rbac

I'm learning RBAC as I go, and I've created roles, permissions, role_perm, and user_role tables.

I created a trigger to automatically add new permissions to the superadmin role in my role-perm table. Then I asked myself, why don't I just use `if ($privileged_user->_can("perm_name" || $privileged_user->is_super_admin)`?

Is it really necessary to add permissions to the superadmin role? or should I just check for the superadmin role explicitly?

Comment: Which resources are you using? Did you check the NIST RBAC profile? What language/framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP & MySQL, and I'm building it from scratch for learning purposes, no framework, but based on Flat RBAC. I'm following some examples from across the web, but mainly my question is about best practices and structure. It just doesn't seem necessary to have to ask, "Can SuperAdmin do this?" when the idea is that SuperAdmin can do *everything*.

Comment: Then again, looking at my question, it might save me some keystrokes in the long run, because I just added to my condition, which might recur pretty often in my project.

Comment: Ok. Whatever you do always strive to keep your app code cleanly separated from your authorization code as a best practice

Comment: @DavidBrossard My strategy so far is to have a basic User class for authentication, then I created a PrivilegedUser class to extend User. The authentication is in the User class, and the permission code is in the PrivilegedUser class. Everything else, once logon is complete, can only access the properties "is_logged_on" and "_can([permission_name])". Does that count as clean separation? This seems to be answering my question, that it IS necessary to add permissions to the superadmin role.